# Operation on 2D nd.array colums organized as a list

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension

I have a list which entries are numpy arrays (2D in this case). 
Example data:

```
   x=list([np.array([[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[111,112,113]]),np.array([[4,5,6],[14,15,16],[114,115,116],[1114,1115,1116]]),np.array([[11,12,13],[111,112,113]]),np.array([[7,8,9],[17,18,19],[117,118,119],[1117,1118,1119]])])
```

I want to execute functions **on** **each column** of each numpy array separate. Some functions have that *axis* command built in but some not e.g. *MinMaxScaler*.

so far I created this list-comprehension:

```
   from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
   scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
   Data=list()
   Data=[[(scaler.fit_transform(np.reshape(x[i][:,j],(-1,1)))) for j in range(x[i].shape[1])] for i in range(len(x))]
```

The problem here is that the list comprehension creates a new list with one 1D- numpy array per iteration.

I tried to use hstack and iterate over the list length.

```
   Data=list()
   L=list(range(len(x)))
   for k in range(len(x)):
          L[k]=np.zeros([x[k].shape[0],x[k].shape[1]])

   Data=[[np.hstack((L[i],scaler.fit_transform(np.reshape(x[i][:,j],(-1,1))))) for j in range(x[i].shape[1])] for i in range(len(x))]
```

But that works not at all. Of course, it stacks on top of the existing zeroes in *L* and it creates another list per iteration.

Other initiations of *L* did not work even if that is not the main problem:

```
   L=list() #IndexError: list index out of range
   L=list(None)*len(x) #TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
   L=list(range(len(x))) #ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
   #...and others tried
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this or do I have to do this with the classic for loops?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Use `L.append(...)`, not `L[k] = ...` in your 3rd code block. Use `L = [None] * len(x)`, not `list(None)*len(x)` in your final code block (although this won't work in your script). This is what happens when you try and use advanced modules (numpy) without learning the basics of python first.

Comment: Dear FHTMitchell 8, thanks for your answer. I tried append before. It is more or less the same problem. It creates another list per iteration. Each list has the amount of columns. What I would need is a hstack of the scaled columns which are then append in a list. And you are right, I came from years of Matlab and self-learned Pyhton...big mistake regarding those rather simple mistakes.

Comment: I should keep a tally of "I think this person came from matlab" guesses I make :) These are very common mistakes for people making that transition. Rule 1: never use `range(len(x))`, there is almost always a better way (iterate directly `for obj in x` or if you need indices `for index, obj in enumerate(x)`. Anyway, see my answer below.

Comment: :-) So true. I actually made myself a cheat sheet for alternatives to range(len()). As I am in a new office, I should reprint that one and hang it on eye hight. Difficult to overwrite the old patterns you entrained over years.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/numpy-for-matlab-users.html

Comment: Wow, this is great. I only had a very incomplete weblink so far. Thank you so much. I get stuck too often on those little Matlab-python conversion problems.

Answer (score 1):

This should work (if i've understood correctly)

```
def f(column):
    ... # function you want to apply to each column

data = [f(column) for matrix in x for column in matrix.T]
```

It's a double for loop, equivalent to (but faster than)

```
data = []
for matrix in x:  # iterate through every matrix in the list
    for column in matrix.transpose():  # iterate through every column in the matrix
        data.append(f(column))
```

Comment: Dear FHT Mitchell, this is a great idea to use a function. I will try to implement the hstack into that as it is like before, each iteration creates its own list entry per column or, without the transpose, row.  Thanks so far

Answer (score 0):

With your `x` (thanks for making it cut-n-paste friendly):

```
In [291]:  x=list([np.array([[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[111,112,113]]),np.array([[4,5,6
     ...: ],[14,15,16],[114,115,116],[1114,1115,1116]]),np.array([[11,12,13],[11
     ...: 1,112,113]]),np.array([[7,8,9],[17,18,19],[117,118,119],[1117,1118,111
     ...: 9]])])
In [292]: x
Out[292]: 
[array([[  1,   2,   3],
        [ 11,  12,  13],
        [111, 112, 113]]), array([[   4,    5,    6],
        [  14,   15,   16],
        [ 114,  115,  116],
        [1114, 1115, 1116]]), array([[ 11,  12,  13],
        [111, 112, 113]]), array([[   7,    8,    9],
        [  17,   18,   19],
        [ 117,  118,  119],
        [1117, 1118, 1119]])]
In [293]: len(x)
Out[293]: 4
In [294]: [i.shape for i in x]
Out[294]: [(3, 3), (4, 3), (2, 3), (4, 3)]
```

I haven't tried to digest your intended processing, but since the arrays have different shapes, I don't see how you can avoid processing each separately.  They can't be combined into any sort of higher dimensional array.

I'm not going to try to apply `fit.transform`, but it is apparent that `Data` is a list of lists.  I don't know what those inner lists contain.

May be it would help if you described the problem, possibly in a simplified form, with just one element of the `x` list.  I prefer to run a concrete example, and look at the resulting arrays and lists in my own Python session.  Word descriptions just aren't clear enough.

Comment: Dear hpaulj, thanks for your answer. My intent with the list-comprehension was to go through each array one by one instead of all at once due to the non-mergeability. The function I use is actually irrelevant (just the one I am using right now). You could also use any other function as long as it does not have the axis command. The problem is how to do any operation on ndarrays-listelements column(or row) wise and then merge the results again to receive the same shape as the input data. Therefore, the problem cannot be described with only one x element

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is probably not the sexiest one it works. If anyone can translate it into a more pythonic way with list comprehension it would be appreciated but not necessary.

with x:

```
   x=list([np.array([[1,2,3],[11,12,13],[111,112,113]]),np.array([[4,5,6],[14,15,16],[114,115,116],[1114,1115,1116]]),np.array([[11,12,13],[111,112,113]]),np.array([[7,8,9],[17,18,19],[117,118,119],[1117,1118,1119]])])
```

Version with function, which is interchangeable:

```
   def theFunction(values,f):
           values=f.fit_transform(np.reshape(values,(-1,1)))
           return values

   from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
   scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1)) #define function 
   data =[0]*len(Neonate)

   for matrix,i in zip(x,range(len(x))):  # iterate through every matrix in the list           
       for column in matrix.transpose():  # iterate through every column in the matrix
           col=theFunction(column,scaler) 
           if 'Matrx' in locals():
                  Matrx=np.hstack((Matrx,col)) 
           else:
                  Matrx=col  
       data[i]=Matrx 
       del Matrx
```

without function where you define what to do within the loop itselve:

```
   from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler    
   scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1)) #define function 
   data =[0]*len(Neonate)

   for matrix,i in zip(x,range(len(x))):  # iterate through every matrix in the list           
       for column in matrix.transpose():  # iterate through every column in the matrix
           col=scaler.fit_transform(np.reshape(column,(-1,1)))
           if 'Matrx' in locals():
                  Matrx=np.hstack((Matrx,col)) 
           else:
                  Matrx=col  
       data[i]=Matrx 
       del Matrx              
   return babies, AnnotMatrix_each_patient, FeatureMatrix_each_patient_all
```